# Fatal problem within my MySql queries

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a problem regarding these 3 queries:

```
select count(*) as rec_count from test_history inner join
  test_detail on test_history.history_id = test_detail.test_history_id 
  where test_history.history_id in ({$_SESSION['history_ids']})
  and test_history.user_id = $userID
```

and

```
select count(*) as correct_answers from test_history inner join test_detail
  on test_history.history_id = test_detail.test_history_id 
  where test_history.history_id in ({$_SESSION['history_ids']}) and
  test_history.user_id = $userID and is_correct = 1
```

and this one

```
select * from test_topics inner join
  test_topics_link on test_topics.`topic_id` = test_topics_link.`topic_id`
  where test_topics_link.test_id in ({$_SESSION['ids_tests']}) and percentage > 0
```

I'm always getting this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') and
test_history.user_id = 82' at line 3

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') and
test_history.user_id = 82 and is_correct = 1' at line 2

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') and percentage > 0' at
line 3
```

Comment: What value has {$_SESSION['history_ids']}? Make sure this expands to a sensible value

Comment: show as the php code. + var_dump($_SESSION['ids_tests'], $_SESSION['history_ids'])

Comment: yes it have right value it have normal userid 82

Comment: @Fouad problem not in $userID but in {$_SESSION['history_ids']}

Comment: @Subdigger var_dump give string(0) ""

Comment: @Fouad this is your problem. at first you should check if the data correct then run sql. `if (!empty($_SESSION['history_ids']) && is_array($_SESSION['history_ids']))` and then use as answered below `implode(',',$_SESSION['history_ids'])` if it is an array...

Answer (score 2):

Since `$_SESSION['ids_tests']`, I suppose, is an array, you should write `implode(',',$_SESSION['ids_test'])`, e.g. in PHP it should be:

```
$query = "select * from test_topics inner join
        test_topics_link on test_topics.`topic_id` = test_topics_link.`topic_id`
        where test_topics_link.test_id in (".
        implode(',',$_SESSION['ids_tests']).") and percentage > 0";
```

Comment: Since you are using the syntax "where column in(...)", I assumed you knew that this syntax works with values lists. That is, the code I posted works, as long as $_SESSION['ids_tests']) is an array. Otherwise, you should not use that syntax and use "where column='...'" instead.